# Where do the step function integral boundaries come from?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

EDIT: I have a confusion about [Heavyside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Suppose I have integral like 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dE_1\int_{0}^{\infty}dE_2\int_{0}^{\infty}dE_3 \delta(2- \gamma-E_1-E_2-E_3)
$$
my first attempt, to solve this integral, would be 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dE_1\int_{0}^{\infty}dE_2\theta(2-\gamma-E_1-E_2)
$$
but I also should change the boundaries and here what I get confused. There are some constraints on the variables:
$$
0 \le E_1 \le 1- \gamma
$$
$$
0 \le E_2 \le 1-\gamma
$$
$$
0\le E_3 \le 1
$$
and the interval should be such like below 
$$
\int_{0}^{1-\gamma}dE_1\int_{1-E_1-\gamma}^{1-\frac{\gamma}{1-E_1}}dE_2
$$
This is not what I expect actually. Can anyone explain the last integral boundaries?

Comment: It seems to me that even line two is not correct. Please notice that the integral over delta function only gives a finite value if it's argument lies in the interval $[0,1]$. What you have written would imply that orignial limits of integration are $[0,\infty]$  which is not true. Instead, you should have something like $\Theta(x)\Theta(1-x)$

Comment: @tired You might be right. This calculation is basically phase space indeed. So the interval should be $[0, \infty]$ But additionally I have constraints on the each energy which I put them as interval boundaries. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Is $\gamma \leq 1$?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the constant $a:=1-\gamma\geq 0$ is assumed to be non-negative. OP's integral then becomes

$$I~:=~\iiint_{[0,a]\times[0,a]\times[0,1]}\!\! dx~dy~dz ~\delta(1+a-x-y-z)$$
$$~=~\int_0^a\!dx\int_0^a\!dy\int_0^1\!dz ~\delta(1+a-x-y-z)$$
$$~\stackrel{\begin{matrix}x^{\prime}=a-x\\z^{\prime}=1-z\end{matrix}}{=}~
\int_0^a\!dx^{\prime} \int_0^1\!dz^{\prime} \int_0^a\!dy~\delta(x^{\prime}+z^{\prime}-y)$$
$$~=~\int_0^a\!dx^{\prime} \int_0^1\!dz^{\prime} \int_0^{\infty}\!dy~\theta(a-y)~\delta(x^{\prime}+z^{\prime}-y)$$
$$~=~\int_0^a\!dx^{\prime} \int_0^1\!dz^{\prime} ~\theta(a-x^{\prime}-z^{\prime})$$
$$ ~=~\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{(a-1)^2}{2}\theta(a-1) .$$
In the last equality we used the interpretation of the double integral as an area of a polygon in the $(x^{\prime},z^{\prime})$ plane.